# Power BI report deployment for end user

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

I have designed a power bi report for a client using data set as his SQL Server database backup in my local system, and publish it on his provided power bi service account, now how do i connect this publish report with my client's local SQL server database?
In other words how my client be able to connect his local system's SQL database with this report?

Comment: Just change the source of the table(s) in the query editor.

Comment: is there any option to change data source in Power BI service?

Comment: You could probably do that with a dataflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameterized connection where you can store your local database access and client database access details, by using:

[image]